# Setting form input width as a percentage of grandparent

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1000px;">
    <input type="text" name="x" style="width: 80%;">
</div>
```

The `#container` is a block level element with a defined width, so I can easily set the width of the `input` as a percentage of `#container` width. So far so good. Next, I need a wrapper around the `input` element to be able to absolutely position some stuff over the `input`. I want the wrapper to wrap around the `input` without any spacing around it. So I try this:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1000px;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
        <input type="text" name="x" style="width: 80%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

This wraps around the `input` nicely, but the `#wrapper` doesn't have a defined width, so the width of the `input` no longer works as expected.

How do I modify this structure so that I could set the width of the `input` as a percentage of the `#container` width, without explicitly setting `#wrapper` dimensions?

Comment: why not setting the width of the wrapper to be 80% and the input will be 100%? it's more logical this way

Comment: you can use ccs variable with css calc()

Answer (score 3):

You can make the grandparent a size container, and then use cq* units on the grandchild

```html
<div id="container" style="width: 1000px; container-type: inline-size;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
        <input type="text" name="x" style="width: 80cqw">
    </div>
</div>
```

Support in 2023 browsers is pretty good. Chromium, Webkit and Gecko all have support for this according to caniuse: https://caniuse.com/?search=container-type